# Socket.io with React and Node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, websocket, socket.io, eventemitter

I'm kinda new using sockets.io and I have a pretty basic question.

I have this code on the server side where I basically try to listen for the event called setName and I pass the username parameter and I emit a new event called "setNameCb" to the client side.

```
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.on("setName", (username) => {
    socket.emit("setNameCb", username);
  });
});
```

And this code on the client side where I try to pass an username when the button is clicked. After that I listen for the setNameCb event from the server side and I try to get the username value.

```
const setNameFunction = () => {
  socket.emit("setName", "Cristian");
};
socket.on("setNameCb", (username) => {
  alert(username);
});

return (
  <div className="App">
    <button onClick={setNameFunction}>set name</button>
  </div>
);
```

Alright, eveything is working, but the problem is that I get multiple alerts with the username and I just can't figure it out why that is happening.

I'd really appreciate an explanation for this one. I know it's a very basic question but that will help me to understand better the concept.

Thank you a lot!

Comment: How many alerts are you getting, always 2 or could be more? It’s possible that you are connected multiple times. If you include and additional socket.id with your username on your emit you could verify this. If you only want reply from the sender event you can also use a built in callback function and reply without and additional emit

Comment: If I put a console.log it's working perfect everywhere except inside of the "setNameCb" event where is the alert in this moment. I also tried to put a socket.id on my emits and it also work properly. The alerts are 2 first time when I restart the server and I press the button, but if I press the button multiple times I get a lot of alerts. So I guess the problem is on the client problem since I receive multiple console.logs only on setNameCb.

Comment: Also, I noticed that I always receive 2 alerts when I press the button. I mean if I press the button 10 times, i receive in total 20 alerts.

Comment: I think you are connected twice on the same session. Please include console.log(socket.id ) along with the alert and see if you are getting the same Id on both sides

Comment: Alright, I see that are high chances to be connected twice on the same session, but how could I fix that or avoid it in the future?

Comment: Finally, I found a solution for my problem. I used useEffect and that fixed that problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The socket listener in react component is created on every render, if not wrapped into useEffect.

```
useEffect(() => {
     const setNameFunction = () => {
     socket.emit("setName", "Cristian");
   };
   socket.on("setNameCb", (username) => {
     alert(username);
   });
   }, [])
```